# Fastest way to insert data using JDBC

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I'm supposed to do a stress testing on my application for which I need 60 million records in a table. The approach I'm following is, first I'm initializing the instance of *Connection* class, then inserting the data using a for loop by *PreparedStatement* using that Connection, and after every 500 rows insertion I'm committing the connection and resetting it.

Using this, I'm able to insert approx 150 records per minute. I just want to know if there's any more optimized way of doing it so that time required for execution is minimal

Comment: Investigate batch inserts or load the data using the Oracle utilities instead of your code.

Comment: Committing in a loop is not going to improve performance in Oracle - the opposite is the case. Only commit once at the end of your transaction.

Comment: But 150 rows per minute is ***way*** to slow. I can get about 1 million per minute with a local server (narrow table with 6 columns)

Comment: Did you try Bulk Insertion Operation?It will insert very quickly compared with batch insert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jdbc batch inserts:

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
int count = 0;
for(loop construct here) {
    count++;
    ps.setString(1,someString);
    // ... and so forth
    ps.addBatch();

    if (count%500 ==0)
        ps.executeBatch()
}
ps.executeBatch();
```

Comment: Hi! do i need to execute ps.clearBatch(); after the execute?

Comment: @MarianoL No, you shouldn't need to do that. `executeBatch` should flush the last batch. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58522625/does-executebatch-also-clear-the-list-of-commands