# Does executeBatch() also clear the list of commands?

Tags: java, jdbc, batch-updates

The documentation of [`Statement.executeBatch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch()) is not clear on this, but I assume that calling it will empty the `Statement` object's current list of SQL commands in the same way as [`clearBatch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#clearBatch()) does. I'm also assuming the same is true for [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

I suppose it is possible to continue using the `Statement` after calling [`Statement.executeBatch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch()), i.e. add another batch of commands and execute them.

Comment: It's not only possible, it's the whole idea of batching that you keep using the same objects.

Comment: @Kayaman I just wonder why the Javadoc doesn't mention that the comand list gets emptied after executeBatch()

Comment: To me it's implied. The batch is executed and done with.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although not explicitly mentioned in the API documentation of `executeBatch`, the behaviour is specified by the [JDBC 4.3 Specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr221/index3.html) in section *14.1.2 Successful Execution*:

> The statement's batch is reset to empty once executeBatch returns.

Although this is specified in a section called 'Successful Execution', it is also the intended behaviour for unsuccessful execution.

In short, when you call `executeBatch()` the current batch of statements is submitted to the database server and cleared.